# Jetpack Compose - Open web view with close button

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose

I have to open a web view when a button is clicked, and I'm asking how to open this web view inside the application with Jetpack Compose. I noticed that the majority of applications when they open a web view they show a close and option button at the top and I'm wondering how they do it. Here an example:

[image]

I'm already able to open a web view, but I don't know how to show this icons and the top bar in that way.

My actual code:

```
@Composable
fun loadWebUrl(url: String) {
     AndroidView(
       factory = {
         WebView(this).apply {
             webViewClient = WebViewClient()
             loadUrl(url)
         }
      }
   )
}
```

Someone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/) SDK.

I wrote [this article](https://nglauber.medium.com/chrome-custom-tabs-para-android-6ca1d3de93) (in Portuguese) a few years ago, not sure if it's still valid.

Comment: This answer is not helpful in the context of Jetpack Compose.